# Load Preferences for nonexistent class

Tags: java, preferences

Our program stores user settings using the Preferences class, accessed via `Preferences.userNodeForPackage()`. We just finished a major refactor and discovered that all of the user settings are forgotten post-refactor, because the class passed to `userNodeForPackage()` is different. E.g. instead of `org.foo.MyClass` we now have `org.foo.bar.MyClass`.

I want to "import" the old Preferences so our users don't notice things being forgotten. If necessary I can manually copy individual key/value pairs across from the old Preferences object to a new one, but I must be able to get that old Preferences object first. Without access to the old class, I don't see how this is possible.

Am I missing something? I see the `Preferences.node()` / `Preferences.nodeExists()` methods which seem promising, except that they only operate on an existing Preferences that contains the desired node. Thus we'd have to be able to get a tree that contains the old root node, and we have no classes above where that old node was (part of the point of refactoring was de-flattening our hierarchy).

I'd really rather not pollute our nice clean source code with dummy files, just so we can access old preferences. Can you assign a package to an anonymous class generated at runtime, perhaps? Or is there some other way to get a Preferences object for a specific package short of passing in the class for that package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could leverage [`Preferences#userRoot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userRoot())

Comment: If it's only the one class, then perhaps you could provide an empty `org.foo.MyClass` for the sole purpose of accessing (and perhaps moving) the preferences.

Comment: @RC Ah, yes! That's all I needed; from there I can sequentially call `.node(path element)` on the nodes to get to the old structure. Thanks! @JohnBollinger that's the "pollute our nice clean source code" solution that I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

RC's comment of using `Preferences.userRoot()` is what I needed -- that gets you the root of the entire Preferences tree, and you can then traverse it using `Preferences.node()` to get to whatever value you need. Thanks, RC!